# Como obtener el mes de una fecha (dd/mm/yyyy) en bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Lo que deberia hacer este codigo es guarda en una variable las fechas.
    Despues recorre ese vector y me guarda en una variable "a" el mes de esa fecha.
    El formato de la variable array_fechas es 
    dd/mm/yyyy

```
 read -a array <<< "${array_fechas[$i]}"
                for element in "${array[@]}";do
                  a=$(date -%m "$element")  

                done`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podría funcionar si lo guardas en

```
MES=$(date -d "$D" '+%m')
```

Y tras ello lo muestras

```
echo "Mes: $MES"
```

Comment: Me muestra los dias de la fecha. Pero gracias ya tengo por donde empezar

Comment: Me habré saltado algo, lo siento, pero si te sirve me alegra al menos haber ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la fecha puede definir un formato:

```
a=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
```

[referencia](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/)